# Forwarding emails from non-existing subdomain?

Tags: php, email, cpanel, forward

I have added A name record for subdomains in DNS settings, 
so if you type

```
notexistingsubdomain.mysite.com
```

it redirects to

```
mysite.com
```

And I also have a script that pipes emails,

**pipe.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "someone@hotmail.com";
while (!feof($fd))
{
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);


mail('admin@mysite.com','From my email pipe!','"' . $email . '"');

?>
```

if someone sends email to

```
notexistinguser@mysite.com
```

it comes to

```
admin@mysite.com
```

What I couldnt able to do is that

I want to forward all emails to my domain's email (even to non existing sub domains) like

```
something@notexistingsubdomain.mysite.com
```

to

```
admin@mysite.com
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: If you are using CPANEL, activate the email catchall feature.
http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/email/catch_all_email.htm

Comment: I think you need an MX records, not an A record for this.

Comment: WHy even use PHP for this Simply setup an alias or catch all on your mail server

Comment: Add an `MX` record for `*.mysite.com`, and rewrite on your email server? I don't know what MTA CPanel uses, but [in postfix it should be easy](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html).

Answer (score 2):

I want to preface this with: **Catch-all *antyhing* in email is a bad idea unless you like massive amounts of spam.** This is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it, but if you're not inclined to listen to reason then this is how you do it correctly:

1. Create a wildcard A and MX records:

   Yes, you need an A record. Some MTAs will refuse to send to a domain/subdomain that does not have an A record.

   ```
   *.yourdomain.com. IN A     1.2.3.4
   *.yourdomain.com. IN MX 10 mail.yourdomain.com
   ```
2. Set up a wildcard domain alias in your MTA software:

   - TBH: I really doubt you'd be able to set this up via CPanel, I think they'd make the [reasonable] assumption that no one in their right mind would do this.
   - It should be technically possible, though you will need to hand-edit some config files in creative and likely undocumented ways. You could definitely do this in Postfix, and you can do anything in Sendmail with enough gumption. Other MTAs... I can't really say for certain.
3. Sob hysterically when your catch-all mailbox either hits its quota daily or, if no quota is assigned, your mail server's disk fills weekly.
4. Wonder why you ever did this.

Oh, and unless this is a dedicated server that you are the sole admin for I would advise against this. If someone did this, or even attempted this, on a server that I manage I would track them down and do very unpleasant things to them.

Comment: Thanks, but whats the 1.2.3.4 numbers, are they belong to ip of my server ? And do I need mta ? Whats that

Comment: Yes, the IP of your server. [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). My advice: seriously just stop even considering this. In addition to being a bad idea it's way above your current skill level and you're probably going to wind up breaking your mail server if you're not super careful.

Comment: Believe me I have a very good and reasonable thing to do that. But I cant. In cpanel > edit DNS zone (Advanced)
There is no MX option to add. Where can I add it ?